# CI/CD package is different from local package [jessie/stretch inconsistency]

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I run docker on local machine with following *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM python:3


WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libhunspell-1.3-0
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 9876

CMD ["python","flask_compose.py"]
```

It got **libhunspell** from following repository (**jessie**):

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [94.4 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [623 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2434 B]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [23.0 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9064 kB]
```

And everything is fine (image build and run successfully).

Unfortunately, when I run docker on gitlab repository with the same *Dockerfile* it calls update apt-get from another repository (**stretch**):

```
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [440 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [12.1 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [9530 kB]
```

Due to this inconsistency gitlab CI/CD throws following exception:

```
E: Unable to locate package libhunspell-1.3-0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libhunspell-1.3-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libhunspell-1.3-0'
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libhunspell-1.3-0' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 100
```

Does anyone knows how change my *Dockerfile* that local and gitlab uses the same package repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There current tag for python:3 points to a Debian stretch based image. To update your local environment, run a `docker pull python:3` or run your build with the `--pull` option.

You can also select a more specific tag to force your desired base image used by python. See the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) page for python to see all the possible tags, e.g. `python:3-jessie`.

Answer (score 0):

From [gitlab official forum](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/10/12/automated-debian-package-build-with-gitlab-ci/) I found a solution which fixed my problem.

1) define a `setup.sh` file and following command:

```
echo "deb http://pkg.adfinis-sygroup.ch/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list  
echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list  
echo "deb http://pkg.adfinis-sygroup.ch/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get update  
apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libhunspell-1.3-0
```

2) In `Dockerfile` add following commands:

```
From python:3
ADD  setup.sh /opt/  
RUN  /bin/bash /opt/setup.sh
```

**PS**: Although my hack works very fine, I prefer @BMitch solution.

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

By extending @Bmitch solution I decrease image size from ~600 to ~150 with following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3-slim-jessie

WORKDIR .

# hunspell deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libtool libc6-dev gcc g++ build-essential libhunspell-1.3-0

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python","flask_compose.py"]
```